# AngularJs SmartTable: adding Template variables

Tags: angularjs, smart-table

I use [SmartTable](http://lorenzofox3.github.io/smart-table-website/) , in that table I have pagination template. 
In the footer of the table I need to dispay "page 1 of X", so I use a html template:

```
<tfoot>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="{{ct.headCells.length}}" class="text-center">
            <div st-items-by-page="itemsPerPage" 
                 st-pagination="" 
                 st-template="/templates/pagination.custom.html">
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tfoot>
```

In my `pagination.html` template I have

```
<li><page-select>{{currentPage}}</page-select> of {{numPages}}</li>
```

All good, `currentPage` and `numPages` are well displayed.

Now, I need to translate the word `of`, say, in French, so I added a new variable `$scope.ofText = "de"`... and I use it in the HTML template:

```
<li><page-select>{{currentPage}}</page-select> {{ofText}} {{numPages}}</li>
```

does not display any text instead of `{{ofText}}`...

What should I do to add custom variables in my template?

Comment: where you able to get your issue resolved?

Comment: I ended up with `st-template="/templates/pagination.{{lang}}.html">`...

Answer (score 0):

@Serge, You can add it in the "pageSelect.directive.js" file. I have added the translation as a scope variable in the directive inside the link function and it is displayed. Please see the plunker.

https://plnkr.co/edit/bunKjbMpQm8bevUYacFt?p=preview

```
angular.module('myApp')
    .directive('pageSelect', function() {
      return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: '<input type="text" class="select-page" ng-model="inputPage" ng-change="selectPage(inputPage)">',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
          scope.$watch('currentPage', function(c) {
            scope.inputPage = c;
          });
          scope.ofStr="de";
        }
      }
    });
```